# How can I make an overline text in Proteus?

Tags: microprocessor, proteus

How do I put an overline above my text in Proteus? I have tried putting in an overline using Word but I get this error instead:

[image: Proteus String Error]

Comment: If I remember correctly, in Proteus you put a dollar sign before and after the text that should have the overline. Like `M/$IO$`. Try that.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked

Comment: Great. I just posted the above as an official answer so that you can mark the question as answered.

Comment: @DyBancs - Hi, Since you are new here, please see [this page](/help/someone-answers) (from the [help] ) to explain how you can accept an answer to mark that as the one which solved your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Proteus, you can make text overlined by typing a dollar sign before and after the text that should be overlined.

For example `M/$IO$` will generate a line over the `IO` part of the text.